# Orden de ejecución de varios update con SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo un problema con un procedimiento de actualización de valores a un mismo campo. En principio pensaba que poniendo varios updates uno detrás de otro en un procedimiento *SQL Server* se ejecutaban de manera secuencial (hasta que no termina un `update` no empieza otro) pero creo que no me esta funcionando de esta manera.

Por ejemplo, el procedimiento sería el siguiente:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE test
AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE Tabla SET CampoMarca = 'CANON' WHERE Mercado = 'Informatica'
  UPDATE Tabla SET CampoMarca = 'CANON VALENCIA' WHERE Proveedor = 'VALENCIA'
END
```

Es un ejemplo parecido al que tengo. Lo que quiero con este procedimiento es que se ejecute primero el primer `update` y cuando se haya realizado se ejecute el segundo. A día de hoy parece que el primer `update` tarda más en acabar y por tanto nunca tengo `CANON VALENCIA` sino que todo me lo deja a `CANON` (incluso cuando el proveedor es Valencia).

¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo hacer para mantener la jerarquía de varios updates?

**EDITO**: Actualizo información porque estoy perdido totalmente. Este procedimiento se lanza desde un SSIS y me da el problema que os comentaba. Lo curioso es que si ejecuto el procedimiento desde el *SQL Server Management* me funciona sin problemas, es decir, mantiene el orden.... es normal?

Comment: No intentaste habilitar el Sql Profiler de sql server para poder tracear como se ejecutan los update ? inia el Profiler y que el SSIS inicie la tarea para asi ver como se da cada operacion

Answer (score 6):

Te acabas de encontrar con el [problema de Halloween](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halloween_Problem).

---

Tienes dos posibles soluciones:

- Divides los `UPDATE` en varios procedimientos.
- Los juntas en un solo `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 4):

He encontrado otra solución finalmente. Utilizando CASE en la sentencia UPDATE puedo realizar las modificaciones sin problemas. Ejemplo:

```
UPDATE Tabla
SET CampoMarca = CASE
     WHEN Proveedor = 'VALENCIA' THEN 'CANON VALENCIA'
     WHEN Mercado = 'CANON' THEN 'CANON'
END
```

Hay que tener cuidado en incluir la más importante al ppio para que entre en ese when y no en los siguientes y ya está. Creo que es correcto.

Comment: Entonces aplicaste el segundo consejo de @jordi-castilla en donde comento "Los juntas en un solo update"